# Useful applications of applied category theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question, applied-mathematics

Led by John Baez, applied category theory (e.g. [1]) seems to accumulate much popularity. As someone who has noticed the importance of category theory in pure mathematics (e.g. homotopy theory, tqfts, Khovanov homotopy type), I wonder how it can be applied to real-life problems too.
**However**, it seems that there are lots of jargons so far, while the value of the end-result remains unclear (e.g. [1], again).

#### Question

I wonder what are some new results concerning applied problems. Or at least are there cases which are made "much clearer" (or more succinct) while expressed in terms of applied category theory?

#### Reference

- [1] [*Applied category theory
  in chemistry, computing,
  and social networks* by
  John Baez, Simon Cho, Daniel Cicala, Nina Otter,
  and Valeria de Paiva, Notices AMS 2022](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/202202/rnoti-p292.pdf)

Comment: What does *real-life problem* mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson For example, things related to chemistry, computing, physics, social networks. However, I don't know how to define them though (e.g. What is chemistry? What does it mean? What is water? What is life? What is meaning? What is what?)